# How can i change data locality on Apache Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I 've a problem with data locality in Spark.
I'd like to know if I've the possibility to say to Spark how data should be partitioned on the nodes.

For example, I've a file on HDFS, and I want to get an RDD. I'd like to partition that data depending on a specific attribute of this data(for example depending on the value of the last column of this data).

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can implement custom partitioner.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of behaviors are controlled by the RDD subclass that you are creating, in your example is an Haddoop or a NewHadoopRDD depending which Hadoop API are you using.
In each RDD subClass you can override the getPreferedLocations method which is the one that says where are computed each Partition.

As @user52045 said you can implement a custom partitioner but the data will be send to each machine of your cluster because you will have first a HadoopRDD and then you have to apply the partitionBy(CustomPartitioner) method in order to have the data where you design in your partitioner.

i hope this will be useful

Comment: So as you said, I've two ways : 
1- Implement a custom partitioner, working with partitionBy(..), but it is done on an existing RDD, it 's not before creating the RDD.

2- Modify the code that creates RDD to override the getPreferedLocations. So, when i call for example  myrdd = sc.textFile(), this will work with my version of getPreferedLocations. 

It's right?